# API call to GET /orders/<order-id> returns 404 Not Found for a cancelled order

Tags: coinbase-api

This is a simple question for Coinbase / GDAX REST API developers.

Can a call to `GET /orders/<order-id>` return 404 Not Found for a cancelled order that has partial fills?

Answer (score 0):

NO, If you are requesting `GET /orders/<order-id>` and it return 404 Not Found that means it fully cancelled your order.

See here is the link where in GDAX Doc They are already mentioned.

https://docs.gdax.com/#list-orders